# Помогите с установкой значения cookie!

Tags: php, cookie

ситуация такая. хочу сохранить в куки два слова разделенных запятой и пробелом.
"Город, Область"

Что делаю:

$result=iconv("windows-1251","utf-8",$value);

setcookie("name",$result,time()+3600,"/",$COOKIE_DOMEN);

что вижу сохранилось в куки?

"%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%2C+%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C"

все то что нужно... но как избавиться от знака +???

нужно чтобы пробел заменялся %20 а не плюсом.. я как новичок уже не знаю что и делать. плюс появляется в самой функции setcookie т/е/ всякие функции вроде str_replace не прокатывают..

Comment: + - это пробел, зачем вам его убирать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выдержка из **[документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php)**

> Стоит отметить, что значение cookie
> перед отправкой клиенту подвергается
> URL-кодированию. При обратном
> получении значение cookie декодируется
> и помещается в переменную, с тем же
> именем, что и имя cookie. Если вы не
> хотите, чтобы значения кодировались,
> используйте функцию **[setrawcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setrawcookie.php)**

Вышеупомянутая функция не подвергает данные кодированию.
Чтобы пробел заменялся на %20, вам нужно использовать функцию **[rawurlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.rawurlencode.php)**

```
$result=iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $value);
setrawcookie("name", $result, time()+3600, "/", $COOKIE_DOMEN);
```

Comment: большое спасибо! к сожалению, потратил кучу времени и читал не те сайты с документацией - про raw ни слова(